# Sequelize TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

```
Executing (default): SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Characters' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dev'
D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\utils.js:364
  return s.replace(new RegExp(tickChar, 'g'), '');
           ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at Object.removeTicks (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\utils.js:364:12)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.quoteIdentifier [as _quoteIdentifier] (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\query-generator.js:590:33)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.quoteIdentifier (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:954:19)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.quoteTable (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1037:20)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.attributeToSQL (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\query-generator.js:416:39)
    at MySQLQueryGenerator.attributesToSQL (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\mysql\query-generator.js:441:45)
    at MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:222:38)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Function.sync (D:\GDrive\dev\hanghae\실전\dev\node_modules\sequelize\src\model.js:1353:7)
```

While creating a new table, I'm having this error.

All referenced types are fine. userId in Users is defined as MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED, titleId and fieldId as TINYINT.UNSIGNED
I can't see any typos nor can find any similar issue from others.
Does anybody have an idea, please?

below is my charater model code

```
import sequelize from '../config/connection';
import { Fields, Titles, Users } from '../models';
import {
    Model, DataTypes,
    InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes,
    CreationOptional, ForeignKey
} from 'sequelize'


class Characters extends Model<
    InferAttributes<Characters>, InferCreationAttributes<Characters>
>{
    declare characterId: CreationOptional<number>;
    declare userId: ForeignKey<number>;
    declare titleId: ForeignKey<number>;
    declare fieldId: ForeignKey<number>;

    declare name: string;
    declare job: string;
    declare level: number;
    declare attack: number;
    declare defense: number;
    declare hit: number;
    declare mana: number;
    declare exp: number;

    declare createdAt: CreationOptional<number>;
    declare updatedAt: CreationOptional<number>;

    // declare User: NonAttribute<Users>
    // declare Title: NonAttribute<>;
    // declare Field: NonAttribute<>;
};

Characters.init({
    characterId: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Users,
            key: 'userId'
        }
    },
    titleId: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Titles,
            key: 'titleId'
        }
    },
    fieldId: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Fields,
            key: 'fieldId'
        }
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    job: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false
    },
    level: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false
    },
    attack: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false
    },
    defense: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false
    },
    hit: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false
    },
    mana: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false
    },
    exp: {
        type: DataTypes.MEDIUMINT.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: (Date.now()/1000)|0 + 60 * 60 * 9
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: (Date.now()/1000)|0 + 60 * 60 * 9
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Characters'
});


export default Characters;
```

Comment: I wrote the file again, and now it is working. I've checked diffchecker and the old model nd the new model are perfectly the same. So this really is a weird stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that maybe your tables were not created/synced with the sequelize instance

I had the same issue and when I synced my database connection the problem was solved. Thats why maybe when you created the file again, it worked

Update 1/10/2022:

Here's an axemple of my code:

```js
// your sequelize instance connected with your database
const sequelize = await new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'foo',
        storage: 'bar'
});

// initialization of your models...
YourModel.init(
        {
            foo: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
                allowNull: true
            }
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            tableName: 'bar',
            timestamps: true
        }
);

...

// and then: synchronize the sequelize instance with your database and the needed data for sequelize to properly work will be available
await sequelize.sync();
```

Also check the official documentation for reference: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33569890)

Comment: thanks!! I think I've synced when the server started, but syncing from the model might be different. I'll try this out later when I have the same issue.